# Non-intrusive way to block cellphones from recording video at a public recital?

Tags: technology, hard-science, earth

Principal Noyoucantdoit is a man of absolutes. Maybe he's a Sith, some kids do make that parallel. But that is just noise.

The Christmas recital is coming and with it comes the ban of the back row. Parents making awful videos (with cellphones standing up) with the screen brightness at MAX, blinding those behind them. A veritable forest of LED screens in the front, ruining the experience for everyone.

He wants the cellphones gone. He's hired a professional video crew, the full 2-hour editted video video disk will be sold for $100 a week after the recital. He informed everyone of that and requested for the umpteenth time that nobody records video. But there's no denying the angsty oversharing parents from ruining the kids' privacy.

However, he can't:

1. Confiscate the cellphones.
2. Hack the cellphones.
3. Install/run software in the cellphones.
4. Search the parents.
5. Kick offenders out.
6. Interrupt the recital to call out someone using a cellphone.

He wants the recital to be a good experience for everyone so there won't be any commotion or scene if someone records. He's doing it for the kids (in his own distorted worldview).

He knows that nobody will listen to a request to be polite. Is there any early XXI technology (< 2020) he can use to dissuade the parents from recording?

#### This is [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) so a full technical explanation of how your solution works and why is expected.

Comment: This sounds like a plot element, not a worldbuilding problem

Comment: @L.dutch nope. that's a technical question. What technology can be used to block cellphones from recording video. There's a fine balance between one-line questions. I just added a character and a setting as decoration. This question can be reduced to a single line. The title.

Comment: Not realy world building though is it?

Comment: @slarty you can ignore the fluff and just look at the constraints and title.

Comment: Require all attendees to sign a contract that they will not use recording devices and then issue a massive (e.g. $1000 or more) fine to offenders? This may or may not work, though...

Comment: This seems like an abuse of market power much more than a technical problem. The principal will be promptly (and correctly) suspended pending investigation after first local media report appears featuring the $100 price tag.

Comment: What you need is a robocall bot, doesn't have to be a sophisticated one. The school surely has the phone numbers of all parents. Just keep calling them constantly, boomers and most millenials don't know how to block calls or to put their cell phones in airplane mode. Everytime they get a call this will disrupt their recording.

Comment: @Renan And then the one parent who actually knows how stuff works gets everyone involved arrested for denial of service, harassment, etc.

Comment: @ZeissIkon good point, there's that advantage too.

Comment: BTW, I'm a boomer (last of the generation) and I routinely block spam calls, know how to airplane and silence my phone, etc.  Then again, I've been building my own computers since 8088 was a reasonably current processor.

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem that movie theaters face today. One proposed technology is to flash IR light that the cameras pick but that the humans don't notice.

> National Institute of Informatics, Japan in co-operation with Sharp, has developed a technique to render any recording unwatchable by flashing pulses of infra-red (IR) light from behind the cinema screen. The pulses pass through tiny holes in the screen originally designed to allow through sound, and cause interference to any video cameras held by members of the audience. The IR light, while invisible to human eyes, is also impossible to filter out without rendering the recording too blurry to watch. The team says best results are achieved at a speed of 10 pulses per second.
>
> via [fareastgizmos.com](https://fareastgizmos.com/other_stuff/ir_light_from_behind_the_cinema_screen_prevents_pirates_from_recording_films_at_movie_theaters.php)

You don't have a screen at your recital, but perhaps some IR reflective elements on the stage would make the recording obnoxious enough to achieve your objective.

To make sure the official recording isn't affected, have the official camera use active shudder synced with the lights or some form of post-processing. Taken from another proposed movie theater system:

> The technology utilizes liquid crystals to clutter video frames with noise, objects, and shading. In addition, a light would be shone at a certain frequency which runs out of sync with the movie content, and so any illegal recordings will contain stripes, rendering the recording unusable.
>
> While the lighting would not obscure the viewing quality as long as people are watching through synchronized polarized active shutter glasses -- similar to glasses used in 3D cinemas -- which filter out these objects, if a camcorder attempts to record the screen, the footage itself will be obscured.
>
> via [zdnet.com](https://www.zdnet.com/article/philips-takes-on-cam-piracy-with-new-ambient-light-technology/)

Comment: The Sharp system depends on the IR coming from the entire area of interest (the whole screen).  Might be pretty hard to arrange this for a concert hall (auditorium, gymnasium, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Include a laser light show as part of the recital.  A fairly modest amount of laser power will permanently damage the sensor in any sort of video or digital camera (even if it's shut off).  A simple warning at the opening of the recital that the laser show may permanently damage your $1500 flagship phone (in a way that won't be covered under warranty) might well do the trick.

Well, perhaps a minor problem -- a level of power that will damage a digital sensor will also cause permanent retinal damage.  Perhaps issuing laser goggles at the door will help reinforce the hazard to those expensive cell phones.

Oh, the professional video crew?  They have a laser filter on their camera(s).  Pity the video won't show the laser show, but it'll still give a beautiful record of the recital itself.  Oh, and the parents won't be able to see the lasers through the issued goggles, either, but taking them off would be a bad idea...

Comment: Seems excessive... you might be able to get away with rastering a rather less hazardous near-IR laser across the audience, on the assumption that cameras will have substantially higher sensitivity in that part of the spectrum and will be dazzled but the meatbags won't notice. Need to make sure that the official camera is protected from it, however.

Comment: @StarfishPrime All digital cameras made for visible light have IR block filters behind the lens -- precisely *because* the sensors are so much more sensitive to IR than they are to visible light.  Your phone will will pick up the IR LED from your TV remote, but it isn't so easily dazzled because of the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Put bright lights just above the stage pointed at the audience, keep the stage somewhat dimmer. As long as the lights don't have much glare, they should not cause much discomfort to the audience, but they will render any digitally recorded video overexposed.

Since you will be recording as well, use cool LED lights for the audience and warm lights for the stage, then use a filter on the lens to get rid of the incident light. Colour can be corrected in postprocessing. Ideally, if you could get UV lamps of that intensity which would not be otherwise harmful, those would not disturb the audience experience, but provide the same effect.

Comment: As I understood the question, the goal isn't to prevent people from having *useful* recordings (i.e. in order to force them to buy the professional recording), it's to prevent them from *obnoxiously using mobile devices*, which this doesn't really solve.

Comment: @Matthew: If it works as I expect, all they'll see on their screens is a white field. Unless they're recording blindly, I expect them to stop at that point

Comment: ...then perhaps you can clarify your answer? You (originally) said "blurred", not "hopelessly overexposed". I can easily envision a level of blur that would make the recording less than satisfactory but could easily be overlooked at the time, especially on a small phone screen. (Keep in mind also the OP mentioned "before 2020". If the setting is circa 2010, phone screens were smaller back then. OTOH, so was the recorded video...)

Comment: @Matthew: That's the word. Thanks. I couldn't remember it

Answer (score -1):

**Dressing Room**

You could dress the kids with a special reflective clothing [RC](https://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/anti-paparazzi-reflective-clothing/) In every presentation telling everyone that video recording and photos aren't allow in each event.

As you are correct, people wouldn't comply with that request and they would record everything.

In the moment that they are trying to upload those clips in their social networks the will notice the ugly true, that everything is just white noice.

After a few  presentations in those conditions people would understand the situation and stop trying even if you are not using the reflective cloth. And your play would be enjoyed as you demanded.

Comment: ...but this will wreck the "official" recording as well. It also has the same issue as nzaman's answer (see my comment there).

Comment: @Matthew you can easily tape and edit one of final rehearsals and end up with a better recording that the live presentation performance, including better angles and less noice. No one is allow to tape the live presentation.